# Node.js rounds my sql result. how do i prevent this?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, phpmyadmin, node-mysql

I am requesting a bigint from my database. However, Node.js alters the value of my request, so that my program doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
let query = `SELECT transcriptchannel FROM guilds WHERE guild_id = 933323734322913301;`
    sql.query(query, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        
        console.log(result);
}
```

The console logs:

```
[ RowDataPacket { transcriptchannel: 946134226196123600 } ]
```

However, if i run the same statement in PHPmyAdmin, it looks like the following:

```
SELECT transcriptchannel FROM guilds WHERE guild_id = 933323734322913301;
```

it returns:

```
946134226196123658
```

Why does Node.JS round the value up and how do i prevent it?

Comment: Javascript numbers don't have that many digits of precision. You should probably be using strings rather than numbers for guild IDs.

Comment: Does not change anything :/ but you have a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the number is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Please try following and see if you are getting expected value:

```
const sql = mysql.createConnection({supportBigNumbers: true, bigNumberStrings: true});
```

reference - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql